# Squid both transparent and forward mode

Tags: proxy, squid, transparent-proxy

Is it possibile to configure squid for both transparent and forward-authenticated mode (maybe listening two different tcp ports)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, just add two port lines like :

```
http_port 3128
http_port 3130 transparent
```

And of course, the transparent will not be authenticated, as it is not possible

Comment: But can I use authentication for the forward proxy (3128) and obviously not for the transparent one (3130) or should I use different squid daemons?

Comment: I can't answer : I don't know. The documentation is not clear about that. You could maybe test to see.